# How to show and hide my contents when I click my icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I just created a card-form(bootstrap) and in the form,
there are a plus icon and hidden contents(`id=mycontent_1 with display: none`). what I'm trying to do is listed as follows. 
I tried to do the first one on my java-script but it's not working.

1. when I click plus icon, my function(toggler) should be executed and the icon would be hidden and my contents(text boxes and delete button) have to be visible.
2. similarly in opposite direction, when I click the delete button, my 
   contents(text boxes and a delete button) have to be invisible and the 
   plus icon should be visible.

need your kind helps for my two functions. 
here are my codes for jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/Sanchez/aq9Laaew/219304/

```
       <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" id="cardHeader1" style="visibility: hidden;"> no name </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="toggler('myContent_1');">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id=icon1  onclick="toggler('myContent_1');"></span> Plus 
            </a>
                <div id="myContent_1" class="card-title" style="display: none;" >
              <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text">Number</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="notiSeq_1" name="notiSeq" class="form-control" value="">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">
                      <i class="fa fa-sort-numeric-asc"></i>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text">Title</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="title_1" name="title" class="form-control" value="">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">
                      <i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-actions">
                   <button type="button" id="delBtn_1" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>



function toggler(divId){  

   var tempId = divId.slice(-1);
   var x = document.getElementById("icon" + tempId);
   var y = document.getElementById("cardHeader" + tempId);
   x.style.display = "none";
   y.style.visibility = "visible";
   $("#delBtn_" + tempId).show();
   $("#" + divId).toggle();

}
```

Comment: Your id tag in the following line :<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id=icon1  onclick="toggler('myContent_1');"></span>is missing the two ""
that's a first step

Comment: the only error I have in jsfiddle is Uncaught ReferenceError: toggler is not defined. If I put the script inline in the HTMl between <script> tags then it works. in your project be careful when javasript is loaded.

Comment: Your jsfiddle does not work. I created I CodePen to verify your error, but it works. Does the console of the DevTools shows some errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with you should place you js code on the head before the body.
Afterwards, replace the `a` tag with `button`
Finally call `toggler` function on delete button's onclick

```
<script>
   function hidePlusBtn() {
       $("#plusBtn").hide();
   }

   function toggler(divId) {  
       var tempId = divId.slice(-1);
       var x = document.getElementById("icon" + tempId);
       var y = document.getElementById("cardHeader" + tempId);
       x.style.display = "none";
       y.style.visibility = "visible";
       $("#delBtn_" + tempId).show();
       $("#" + divId).toggle();
   }
</script>  

<div class="col-sm-6">
      ...
     <button 
            id="plusBtn" 
            class="btn btn-info btn-lg" 
            onclick="toggler('myContent_1');">
              <span 
                  class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" 
                  id=icon1  
                  onclick="toggler('myContent_1');">
              </span> Plus 
    </button>
     ...
     <button 
          type="button" 
          id="delBtn_1" 
          class="btn btn-danger" 
          onclick="toggler('myContent_1'); hidePlusBtn()">Delete
     </button>
  ...
</div>
```

Updated Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1s390orm/

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice kboul. but I need one more step. when the delete button clicked, the plus icon also has to be hidden. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean the plus button because right now there is no plus icon?

Comment: Yes the plus button should be disappeared too

Comment: You should really consider refactoring your code as in some parts you use vanilla js and in others jquery. It is not the most elegant way but one approach is to call a second function while clicking delete btn and hide the plus btn. I updated the fiddle and the answer.

Comment: @JinPark Please accept and/or up-vote the answer if it solved your issue